# Swift's dictionary key listing differs from Objective-C

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

Listing dictionary keys behavior in Swift is deferent from Objective-C. 
Objective-C:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"key1": @"One",@"key2": @"Two",@"key3": @"Three"};

for (NSString *myKey in myDict) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@",myKey);
}
```

Objective-C debug output:

```
key: key1 
key: key3
key: key2
```

However Swift behaves differently:

```
let stringOfStrings = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]

for key in stringOfStrings {
    println(key)
}
```

Swift's output:

```
(key2, value2)
(key1, value1)
```

How do I get Swift to perform like Objective-C; i.e., to list only the keys?

Answer (score 5):

The reason it looks like it behaves differently in Swift is that when you iterate through a dictionary you are getting a [Tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_481). This particular tuple has a "key" and a "value". If you want to only access keys, you should capture just that part of the tuple:

```
for (key, _) in stringOfStrings {
    println(key)
}
```

The underscore (`_`) is a placeholder where you would normally capture a variable that indicates you don't actually want to use the variable. If you did have a use for the value as well, you would loop through it like so:

```
for (key, value) in stringOfStrings {
    println("\(key): \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keys` property:

```
let stringOfStrings = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]

for key in stringOfStrings.keys {
    println(key)
}

// key2
// key1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (key, value) in stringOfStrings
```

or to just get the key:

```
for (key, _) in stringOfStrings
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0**

You can access the `NSDictionary` value as followed:

```
let stringOfStrings = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]

for key in stringOfStrings {

print(key.0)
print(key.1)

}
```

Or only to get the keys is

```
for key in stringOfStrings {

print(key.0)

}
```